# MYSQL Syntax error on inner join

Tags: mysql, syntax

im getting this error - right syntax to use near 'int inner join categories as cat on int.categoryID = cat.categoryID GRO' at line 5

my sql -

```
SELECT interest_desc, categoryID, category_desc, MAX(num_in_cat) AS num_in_cat 
    FROM
    (
       SELECT int.interest_desc, int.category_ID, cat.category_desc, 
              COUNT(categoryID) AS num_in_cat
       FROM 
          interests as int 
          inner join categories as cat 
             on int.categoryID = cat.categoryID

       GROUP BY int.interest_desc, int.categoryID
     ) subsel 
     GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID"
```

Thanks

Comment: Look up "quote identifiers" as there is a clash with a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM interests as "int"`.  If your language string delimeter is double quote itself. Prepend the double quote with backslash: `"SELECT * FROM interests as \"int\""`

Comment: Don't use backticks, use double quotes. It's MySQL-specific, besides you cannot use backticks on stackoverflow comments, and on explanation of codes here in stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to backquote your `int`s as they are a reserved keyword.

Alternatively, use a different alias.

```
SELECT interest_desc, categoryID, category_desc, MAX(num_in_cat) AS num_in_cat  
FROM 
( 
   SELECT `int`.interest_desc, `int`.category_ID, cat.category_desc,  
          COUNT(categoryID) AS num_in_cat 
   FROM  
      interests as `int`  
      inner join categories as cat  
         on `int`.categoryID = cat.categoryID 

   GROUP BY `int`.interest_desc, `int`.categoryID 
 ) subsel  
 GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID"
```

Comment: trying to get this script to work i get this - Column 'categoryID' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: You have two `categoryIDs` defined, change your fields in the select.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different alias for your `interests` table.

Also - you'll need to sort out the following:

- `categoryID` vs `category_ID` - which one is correct?
- `count(categoryID)` is ambiguous given that `categoryID` is present in both `categories` and `interests` table

Assuming that the column is `categoryID` on both tables the following should work:

```
SELECT interest_desc, categoryID, category_desc, MAX(num_in_cat) AS num_in_cat 
    FROM
    (
       SELECT intr.interest_desc, intr.categoryID, cat.category_desc, COUNT(cat.categoryID) AS num_in_cat
       FROM interests as intr inner join categories as cat on 
intr.categoryID = cat.categoryID
       GROUP BY intr.interest_desc, intr.categoryID
     ) subsel 
     GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID;
```

Comment: Hi, tom, trying to implement this sql with this code anychance you could have a look. nothing is being outputted :S - http://pastebin.com/ShCPDcex

Comment: Umm. I kinda need to know what data is present in both the interests and categories table to help you any further...

Comment: Use http://sqlfiddle.com instead :-) You also get to know more about the other cousins of MySQL. You will love me forever if you are using http://sqlfiddle.com instead. Try its Text to DDL, it works with tab-delimited(however, your string with spaces must be replaced by non-space), box-delimited data(from MySQL and Postgresql format), and CSV too

Answer (score 0):

Naming a table `int` is a problem.  It can be solved by quoting the table name, but you really should rename it.  For your sanity, and those who will work on it after you.